# Clients can't communicate with each other

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I wrote a chat program that lets multiple users chat. The problem is clients cannot see what the other clients typed. The server is functioning well it accepts multiple clients and their inputs. I created an `ArrayList` to store the list of clients in my server for them to see what the other client typed but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code

Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class myServerSocket {

        int portNumber = 4434;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket clientSocket;
        ArrayList<myServerSocketRunnable> clients = new ArrayList<myServerSocketRunnable>();

        public void runServer() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                }
            } catch(IOException aww) {
                System.out.println(aww.getMessage());
                aww.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                while(true) {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    myServerSocketRunnable client = new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket);
                    clients.add(client);
                    new Thread(new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
                }
            } catch(IOException aww) {
                System.out.println(aww.getMessage()+"\n");
            } finally {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class myServerSocketRunnable extends Thread {

    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String username; 
    String message;

    public myServerSocketRunnable(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while(true) {
                in =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                username = in.readLine();
                message = in.readLine();

                System.out.println(" "+username+": "+message);
                out.println(" "+username+": "+message);
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch(IOException aww) {
            System.out.println(" "+username+" has disconnected!");
            out.println(" "+username+" has disconnected!"); 
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            } catch(IOException aww) {
                aww.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}




public class myServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myServerSocket call = new myServerSocket();

        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("=             Messenger Server          =");
        System.out.println("=========================================");

        call.runServer();
    }
}
```

Client

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Messenger {
    private static String hostName = "127.0.0.1";
    private static int portNumber = 4434;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static BufferedReader in;

    private static String username, content;
    private static JFrame firstFrame, secondFrame;
    private static JTextField userName, userField, clientTextField;
    private static JTextArea clientTexts;
    private static JButton talkButton, sendButton;


    public static void firstGUI(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(null);

        userName = new JTextField("Username :");
        userName.setBounds(10, 35, 70, 20);
        userName.setEditable(false);

        userField = new JTextField();
        userField.setBounds(10, 55, 225, 20);

        talkButton = new JButton("Talk!");
        talkButton.setBounds(85, 100, 70, 35);
        talkButton.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        pane.add(userName);
        pane.add(userField);
        pane.add(talkButton);
        pane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        talkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                username = userField.getText();
                showFrame();
                talkButton.setEnabled(false);
                firstFrame.dispose();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void showGUI() {

        firstFrame = new JFrame("Messenger");
        firstFrame.setVisible(true);
        firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        firstFrame.setBounds(500, 100, 250, 200);
        firstFrame.setResizable(false);

        firstGUI(firstFrame.getContentPane());
    }

    public static void contentGUI(Container pane) {

        pane.setLayout(null);

        clientTexts = new JTextArea();
        clientTexts.setEditable(false);
        clientTexts.setBounds(15, 10, 465, 490);
        clientTexts.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        clientTexts.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 13));

        clientTextField = new JTextField();
        clientTextField.setText("");
        clientTextField.setBounds(15, 525, 360, 25);
        clientTextField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        clientTextField.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        sendButton.setBounds(405, 519, 75, 35);
        sendButton.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        pane.add(clientTexts);
        pane.add(clientTextField);
        pane.add(sendButton);
        pane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                content = clientTextField.getText();
                clientTextField.setText("");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            out.println(username);
                            out.println(content);
                            out.flush();
                            clientTexts.append(in.readLine()+"\n");
                        } catch (IOException aww) {
                            aww.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
    }

    public static void showFrame() {

        secondFrame = new JFrame("Messenger - Client");
        secondFrame.setVisible(true);
        secondFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentGUI(secondFrame.getContentPane());

        secondFrame.setBounds(550, 100, 500, 600);
        secondFrame.setResizable(false);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            showGUI();
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch(IOException aww) {
            userField.setForeground(Color.RED);
            userField.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            userField.setText("Server is not Online");
            userField.setEditable(false);
            talkButton.setEnabled(false);

            aww.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I want to know what part of the code is wrong. Maybe a solution to resolve the problem.

Comment: `"... but it doesn't seem to be working"` -- are hard problems for us to be able to help answer. It's probably time to use a debugger, a logger, or a combination of the two to first identify and *isolate* the error.

Comment: In the future, you should break your code into small, testable components. That way it's extremely easy to figure out which parts work and which parts don't. There are so many responsibilities in each class here that it's very hard for us to find out which part is wrong.

Comment: Why is this: `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);` within a `while (true)` block? Shouldn't that be called only **once**?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i see. I thought putting it in `while` allows multiple clients to enter the server

Comment: @mahurt: but that's not where the clients enter, is it? They enter in the appropriate while loop below it, right?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah it was on `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`

Answer (score 1):

One issue is here:

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
myServerSocketRunnable client = new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket);
clients.add(client);
new Thread(new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket)).start();
```

You're creating **two** myServerSocketRunnable objects, one you add to the clients List and one you place in a thread and run, and that may be a serious problem. Instead create one for both:

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
myServerSocketRunnable client = new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket);
clients.add(client);

// new Thread(new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket)).start(); // NO
new Thread(client).start();     // YES
```

I don't know if this is the cause of your problems, but I do know that it's just not right and needs to be fixed. Also, as I state in comments, this `while (true)` loop doesn't belong:

```
while(true) {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
}
```

Just create your server socket once and move on.

---

Also, where does your Server broadcast data received from one Client to all the other Clients? I would assume that you would use your clients ArrayList for this, but I don't see this being used. The clients cannot magically connect to each other, and the server must provide the glue.

Comment: were your referring to `myServerSocketRunnable client = new myServerSocketRunnable(clientSocket);
clients.add(client);` ? this code is where i store the list of clients into `ArrayList`

Comment: @mahurt: I have shown you what code I refer to. I know that's where you put the clients into the ArrayList, but again you're creating two myServerSocketRunnable objects unnecessarily. But more importantly -- you state that your clients are not communicating -- where is there code that would allow them to communicate?

Comment: `out.println(" "+username+": "+message);` i guess?

Comment: so i need to create this Server broadcast data. Thanks btw

Comment: `out.println(...)` looks to only send text to the one client that it is tied to.